# Ease-in-out on hover Keyframe CSS3

Tags: animation, css, keyframe

Trying to animate a simple rotation with keyframe. That's all good but I hate it how it just stops all of a sudden on mouse off.
I've tried:

```
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

but that only applies to the frames not the animation as a whole.

This is what I have, any help appreciated.

```
@-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
0% {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
} }
```

And the hover

```
a:hover {
-webkit-animation-name: Rotate;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work with keyframes but I'm going to go ahead and assume it will.

In the example I have been working on I wanted an arrow that faces right then on rollover smoothly rotates to point down. Here's the code:

```
div#welcome img{
            -webkit-transition: 1.5s all ease;
            -moz-transition: 1.5s all ease;
            -o-transition: 1.5s all ease;
    transition: 1.5s all ease;               
}

div#welcome:hover img {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);   
}
```

And here's the mark-up fyi:

```
<div id="welcome">
            <h1>Welcome
            </h1>
            <img class="hover" src="images/arrow.png" />
            <p>
               blah blah blah
            </p>
        </div>
```

The trick is, put your transition in the initial state, in this case *div#welcome h1 img* then you put the end result in the action state, that is, the :hover style. This will mean when the user rolls over that  the arrow will rotate smoothly in and then out on roll off.

[The *ease* part of the styling is explained here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp)